# reloading div without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have connected a mysql database with a div container inside form. But when there is a new element in the mysql database, i have to reload the whole page to show the new element inside the div.

The code for div:

```
<form method="post" action="startseite.php">
<div id="message">
<input type="text" name="spind" value="" size="55" maxlength="90">
<button>Senden</button>
</div></form>
```

My Javascript code for the div-container:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight);     
    $("button").click(function(){
    var message = $("input").val();
    var old = $("#content").html();

    $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight);

    }); 
});
```

The mysql database Code:

```
<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost", "hallo", "123")
or die("Fehler im System");

mysql_select_db("hallo")
or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank war nicht erfolgreich");


$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$message = $_POST['spind'];

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO chat
(user, message)

VALUES
('$user', '$message')";

mysql_query($eintrag);

mysql_close($verbindung);
?>
```

I have read that this could be done with AJAX, but maybe there is another way to do that without AJAX.

Comment: *Ahem* => `mysql_select_db("hallo",$verbindung)` ;-) *Plus,* missing `session_start();`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development.

Comment: what do you mean Fred-ii- ?

Comment: You're not passing connection to DB selection and `session_start();` needs to be loaded when using sessions, which isn't shown in your code.

Comment: ok yes but i have session_start() at the top of my php file, there is no problem with the mysql connection, the only problem is that i have to refresh to show the new database information inside the div

Comment: Why do you want to do it without AJAX?

Comment: without AJAX you want to reload *part* of page...may be iframes but i would strongly advice against it!!! :)

Comment: You should use ajax or long polling but ajax is easier.

Comment: You could easily send an ajax `get` request at a `setInterval` an update the div when the second request is different from the first.

Comment: you can do this with server sent events. but you will need an ajax fallback for old browsers and ie. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/ and http://caniuse.com/eventsource

Comment: how do i do an ajax get request? could someone give me a code-example?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a resfull api, that return only the data, then with jquery ajax make the call and add the new element

look 
http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxservice/index.html?ca=dat
tutorials